# How do you center a tikzpicture in a tabular environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I can't figure out how to center this triangle and the text "Equilateral Triangle" in their table cells. Currently, the triangle is hugging the bottom left corner and I want it to be in the middle of the box. Here is the code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture} [scale = 0.5]
            % Draw the triangle
            \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (A) at (5,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (2.5,4.33);
            \draw (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;

            %Draw the line tick marks
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,-0.25) -- (2.5,0.25);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (1.5,2.021) -- (1,2.309);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4,2.309) -- (3.5,2.021);

            %Draw the angles
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](B,A,O)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](A,O,B)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](O,B,A)

            %Tick the Angles
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,3.25) -- (2.5,3.75);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4.5,0.288675) -- (4.1,0.52);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (0.5,0.288) -- (0.9,0.52);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        & 
        \textbf{Equilateral} Triangle \\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Here is the current output:[image]

Comment: Not sure why you are getting so much space around your tikzpicture.  I don't get it with your code.  See what adding `\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);` before the end does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `baseline` of the `tikzpicture`. Here are two examples, one in which it is set to a distance and one in which it is set to coincide with the base of a phantom node at the barycenter of the triangle, at the center of the `tikzpicture`, or just using `\vcenter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5,baseline=0.9cm]
            % Draw the triangle
            \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (A) at (5,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (2.5,4.33);
            \draw (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;
            %Draw the line tick marks
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,-0.25) -- (2.5,0.25);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (1.5,2.021) -- (1,2.309);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4,2.309) -- (3.5,2.021);

            %Draw the angles
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](B,A,O)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](A,O,B)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](O,B,A)

            %Tick the Angles
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,3.25) -- (2.5,3.75);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4.5,0.288675) -- (4.1,0.52);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (0.5,0.288) -- (0.9,0.52);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        & 
        \textbf{Equilateral} Triangle \\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5,baseline={(X.base)}]
            % Draw the triangle
            \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (A) at (5,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (2.5,4.33);
            \path (barycentric cs:O=1,A=1,B=1) node(X){\vphantom{X}};
            \draw (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;
            %Draw the line tick marks
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,-0.25) -- (2.5,0.25);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (1.5,2.021) -- (1,2.309);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4,2.309) -- (3.5,2.021);

            %Draw the angles
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](B,A,O)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](A,O,B)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](O,B,A)

            %Tick the Angles
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,3.25) -- (2.5,3.75);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4.5,0.288675) -- (4.1,0.52);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (0.5,0.288) -- (0.9,0.52);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        & 
        \textbf{Equilateral} Triangle \\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5,baseline={(X.base)}]
            % Draw the triangle
            \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (A) at (5,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (2.5,4.33);          
            \draw (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;
            %Draw the line tick marks
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,-0.25) -- (2.5,0.25);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (1.5,2.021) -- (1,2.309);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4,2.309) -- (3.5,2.021);

            %Draw the angles
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](B,A,O)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](A,O,B)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](O,B,A)

            %Tick the Angles
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,3.25) -- (2.5,3.75);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4.5,0.288675) -- (4.1,0.52);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (0.5,0.288) -- (0.9,0.52);
            \path (current bounding box.center) node(X){\vphantom{X}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        & 
        \textbf{Equilateral} Triangle \\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        $\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
            % Draw the triangle
            \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (A) at (5,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (2.5,4.33);
            \draw (O) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;
            %Draw the line tick marks
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,-0.25) -- (2.5,0.25);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (1.5,2.021) -- (1,2.309);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4,2.309) -- (3.5,2.021);
            %Draw the angles
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](B,A,O)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](A,O,B)
            \tkzMarkAngle [size=0.8cm](O,B,A)
            %Tick the Angles
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (2.5,3.25) -- (2.5,3.75);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (4.5,0.288675) -- (4.1,0.52);
            \draw [line width = 0.5 pt] (0.5,0.288) -- (0.9,0.52);
        \end{tikzpicture}}}$
        & 
        \textbf{Equilateral} Triangle \\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]